# Transfer Mysql database to another computer

Tags: mysql, migration, dump, transfer

I have a `mysql` database filled up and running on a *Windows* computer, is there any tool to transfer the database to another computer (running *Ubuntu*)?

Else I'll just write a `script` to take all the data base into `SQL` and *insert* it on the other computer. Just trying to save some time :)

Thank you all.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The tool you speak of already exists: mysqldump

It dumps out to sql, which you can then copy to another machine and re-load.

eg:

on source:

```
mysqldump -u username -p databasename > dumpfile.sql
```

Then use ftp/rsync/whatever to move the file to the destination machine, and on there, create an empty database to import into and run:

```
mysql -u username -p databasename < dumpfile.sql
```

You'll also need to set up permissions on any users that may have been transferred as well, as they aren't held within the database.

Alternatively, you can copy the files from the mysql data dir - but mysqldump is the easiest/most reliable way.

Worth noting that the table names may become case sensitive on one system when they weren't on the original. It depends on the config at both ends - in particular the case sensitivity (or otherwise) of the filesystem.

Comment: If both versions support it (I think even 4.1 does) using the "-e" option should speed up the process quite a bit.

Comment: What about the situation where you can't do mysqldump as the OS is corrupted? I've heard you can copy .frm, .MYI, and .MYD files.

Comment: You can copy the entire /var/lib/mysql/<dbname> folder in that case. Works well for myisam tables, think there can be problems with innodb. You sometimes need to "create database <dbname>" on the new server and then replace the folder with the copied one to get mysql to notice it - not done this enough times to understand the vagaries properly!

Comment: The solution is old. with the new mysql workbench, you can export/import the database easily.

Answer (score 19):

Rather than exporting the databases one by one, you can export them all with a single command. Then import them.
eg.

```
mysqldump -u username -p --all-databases > c:\alldbs.sql
```

PS- The biggest advantage is that you do not lose the user privileges.

Comment: For restoring in one command: `mysql -u username -p < alldbs.sql`

Answer (score 2):

The on-disk files are 100% compatible between all editions of MySQL. You just have to watch out for the case of the filenames because it matters on Unix, whilst it only sometimes does on Windows.

And remember to stop MySQL before you take a copy. MyISAM files are okay to take a copy whilst running, but InnoDB files are not really safe to do that and Windows' MySQL defaults to InnoDB files.

Answer (score 2):

Be careful with character sets when using mysqldump, especially on windows. I prefer to explicitly set the charset my db uses and use the --result-file=file instead of using the > operator lest something becomes mangled.

Answer (score 1):

From the MySQL documentation:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/copying-databases.html

```
shell> mysqldump --quick db_name | gzip > db_name.gz
```

Transfer the file containing the database contents to the target machine and run these commands there:

```
shell> mysqladmin create db_name
shell> gunzip < db_name.gz | mysql db_name
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make a backup using any gui tool, like Mysql Administrator (http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/gui-tools/ on Windows, aptitude install mysql-admin on Ubuntu) or phpmyadmin (http://www.phpmyadmin.net/home_page/index.php on Windows, aptitude install phpmyadmin on Ubuntu), and then recover it in the other computer.

Answer (score 0):

mysqldump should dump it out correctly and preserve the character set of anything in the database. It is advisable to move to the same version of mysql if you don't want problems.

The file produced by mysqldump is NOT a text file, despite appearances, don't edit it with notepad.exe etc or you'll end up in trouble.

Dumps produced by third party gui tools, especially phpmyadmin, are generally inaccurate and won't necessarily restore correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I often find myself using some variation of this one-liner to copy a database over the network.

```
mysqldump --opt --compress --user=username database | mysql --user=username2 --password=p2 --host=hostB -D database -C database
```

Which I originally read about here:

http://www.igvita.com/2007/10/10/hands-on-mysql-backup-migration/

Answer (score 0):

With new mysql workbench (gui tool), you can easily export the database and import it to the database you want to migrate.